# Compute integral of the form $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-ax^2}$...

Tags: integration

I'm trying to compute the following integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}C^2 e^{-\frac{m}{2\hbar}x^2}e^{-\frac{m}{2\hbar}(x-A)^2}\, dx$$ where $m, \hbar, C$ and $A$ are all real constants.

I'm given the hint that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2} \, dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$$

I assume I need to somehow rearrange the integrand to get it into the form of the hint, but I can't see how to do this.

**EDIT**

Following the suggestion given in the comments I've found the following:

\begin{align*} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}C^2 e^{-\frac{m}{2\hbar}x^2}e^{-\frac{m}{2\hbar}(x-A)^2}\, dx  & = C^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{m}{\hbar}(x^2-Ax+A^2/2)}\, dx \\ 
& = C^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{m}{\hbar}[(x-A/2)^2+A^2/4]}\, dx \\ & = C^2e^{-\frac{mA^2}{4\hbar}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{m}{\hbar}(x-A/2)^2} \, dx \\ & =C^2e^{-\frac{mA^2}{4\hbar}} \sqrt{\frac{\hbar \pi}{m}} \end{align*}

Comment: Try completing the square in the exponent: $-a[x^2 + (x-A)^2]$. Then find the appropriate transformation to bring it to the desired form.

Comment: @Gregory Thank you, I've followed your suggestion of completing the square and I've made an edit with my attempt. Does this look correct?

Comment: That is correct.  I would suggest you paste the edit into an answer so we have one for the question.  After a delay you will be able to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestion given in the comments I've found the following:

\begin{align*} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}C^2 e^{-\frac{m}{2\hbar}x^2}e^{-\frac{m}{2\hbar}(x-A)^2}\, dx  & = C^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{m}{\hbar}(x^2-Ax+A^2/2)}\, dx \\ 
& = C^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{m}{\hbar}[(x-A/2)^2+A^2/4]}\, dx \\ & = C^2e^{-\frac{mA^2}{4\hbar}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{m}{\hbar}(x-A/2)^2} \, dx \\ & =C^2e^{-\frac{mA^2}{4\hbar}} \sqrt{\frac{\hbar \pi}{m}} \end{align*}

Comment: Looks correct to me. Nice work.